# Handling Avro Files from R without using Spark

Tags: r

I have to read an Avro file from R, I have seen that R has two packages sparkAvro and sparklyr that handle Avro files however I can´t install Spark on my local computer so I was wondering whether there are other packages in R without Spark dependency.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use the `ravro` package:
https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/ravro/blob/master/build/ravro_1.0.4.tar.gz

```
install.packages('path_to_tar.gz/ravro_1.0.4.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
df = ravro::read.avro("myavro.avro")
```

But the package is quite old (last commit 7 years ago) and not probably not very fast